# NodeJS - Best way to inherit mongo connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a NodeJS package which works with mongodb using mongoose.

What I want to achieve is that you won't need to pass any connection "config" on init if you know you have already invoked db connection.

Is there some way that my package could use already existing connection?
Or am I missing something, is there some better way for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You create mongoose instance once and make references to it (mongoose = require('mongoose'). So if this instance is connected to DB you no longer need to state connection again.

Comment: what about the case that connection was not created by mongoose ?

Comment: I believe that depends on what made connection, but as far as I know then you'll need to establish a new one. (At least I would recommend that).